# Source Control icons have disappeared in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

Today I installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - RTM.

One item that I noticed that is different is that files listed in the Solution Explorer window not longer display the source control icons beside each file (the lock, unlocked, plus sign for new files, etc.).

Is there a setting that I am overlooking to display these icons?

I have setup Visual Studio 2010 to use my source control client correctly (SourceGear Vault), and it does appear to be working OK -- I'm just used to seeing the little icons by each file.

Anyone out there experiencing this problem? Is there something I can do to get the icons back?

**Update**: SourceGear technical support confirms that this is a known bug, workitem 15021. It doesn't have anything to do with the conversion; it's just that in VS 2010 web projects, only the solution file has the lock icon or "glyph." This will be fixed a maintenance release, but I'm not sure how soon it will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you need to reinstall Vault so it can apply settings to the new IDE.  I have to do the same for Ankh (subversion) to show icons in VS2010.

Comment: It was necessary to reinstall the source control client after the VS 2010 install. That helped, but it turns out this is a known bug of Vault, as described in the update above.